# Different fields on different user types

Tags: laravel-5

I am creating an application where there are different types of users and and there has to be different fields. I have currently made different tables for different users and at registration the fields are saved to different tables. Is there another way to tackle the problem.

Basically there are two users, And I have made the tables

```
normal_user
-id
-username
-email
-profile_photo

another_user
-id
-username
-email
-profile_photo
-city
-phone_number
-first_name
-last_name
```

Is there an easier way or good way ?

Answer (score 0):

Laravel has ACL ( Access Control List ) shipped right from version 5.1. You can make use of Roles and Permissions like how you'd normally see in WordPress. Jeffery Way has explained this excellently in laracasts website.

https://laracasts.com/series/whats-new-in-laravel-5-1

The last 4 videos explains Policies and Gate contracts to implement roles and permissions in Laravel. I believe the last video explains briefly about User Roles and Permissions.